# Navigation bar moving left/right

Tags: html, css

I have two simple pages. The only thing that changes is the content in `<content>` tag.

But the navigation bar is not exactly at same position on the two pages. It's more to the left on the `about.html` page. The navigation bar is ~4px offset on my computer, I need two tabs open and switch between them to see the problem.

I tested it with lastest Chrome and Firefox browsers. The problem only occurs with the computer with a browser at full screen.

After using Chrome debug I found something strange. 
On home page, the html tag is 1513px witdh, with the other page it is 1496px width?!

[Home.html](https://pastebin.com/QPCWBhHR)
[About.html](https://pastebin.com/78daxJ1L)

**Home page**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>
    Nablo
  </title>
 
  <style>
html {
  background-color: white;
}
 
body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
 
a {
  color: #3273dc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
a:hover {
  color: #63ccff;
}
 
a:visited {
  color: #8559da;
}
h2 a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
nav a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
 
footer {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
  </style>
</head>
 
<body>
  <header>
    <h2>
      Nablo
    </h2>
    <nav>
<a href=./home.html>Home</a>
<a href=./docs.html>Docs</a>
<a href=https://google.com>Google</a>
<a href=./about.html>About</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
<content>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p><strong>Nablo</strong> is a light static site generator. It's :</p>
<ul>
<li><strong>Light</strong>.</li>
<li><strong>Fast</strong>.</li>
</ul>
</content>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Made wih ♥ using nablo
  </footer>
</body>
 
</html>
```

**About page**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>
    Nablo
  </title>

  <style>
html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

a {
  color: #3273dc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #63ccff;
}

a:visited {
  color: #8559da;
}
h2 a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

footer {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h2>
      Nablo
    </h2>
    <nav>
<a href=./home.html>Home</a>
<a href=./docs.html>Docs</a>
<a href=https://google.com>Google</a>
<a href=./about.html>About</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
<content>
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
</content>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Made wih ♥ using nablo
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you use chrome DevTools (Inspector) to try and figure out the issue?

Comment: @j08691 I add the code snippets, but with liltte screen there is no issue. Only with computer screen.

Comment: @ChrisL yes, but don't know well how to debug this kind of problem between two pages.

Comment: it's in the exact same position for me

Comment: @ChrisL On a computer on full page (not the stack overflow preview) ? I added an edit to the post. The 2 pages have different size on my web brower (the html tag is 1513px wide or 1496px on the other page). Don't understand why.

Comment: I suggest setting the `width` property of the `body` element, rather than (or in addition to) the `max-width`.

Comment: The `html` tag should be the width of your browser window. If that is varying without changing your window size, you indeed have problems.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Thanks for your help. I already tried the width with or without the max-width property without sucess. Indeed I seem to have problem but don't understand where or why.

Comment: I ran the snippets on full page view and it is exactly the same on both.  your issue must be local (your computer only)

Comment: @ChrisL What browser do you use ? The navigation bar is ~4px offset on my computer, I need two tabs and switch between them to see it. I reproduce the problem with 2 computers with different screen size with 2 different browsers. In fact if this page is not enough long the problem does not occur. I'll update the snippets, we'll notice the problem.

Comment: Now I see it.  Maybe my window wasn't wide enough?  The difference is the scrollbar when the content has more height than the window

Comment: I also see it the same. I can only suggest adding these styles into separate .css file, so you can be sure, that you have the same styles in both files. Use tag <link> in <head>.

Comment: @MartinMelichar in a sperate css file, it's the same. Moreover, pages are programmatically generated, so the style is the same on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's causing this?

It's not just your navigation bar that is *moving*, it's your whole `body` element. Furthermore, it only seems like it's moving, but it's actually working as intended. The value auto on `body`'s margin will always center the `body` element.

The *home page* does not have any scrollbar, but the *about page* has a vertical scrollbar on the right side of the page. The scrollbar takes up some width of the `html` element. As a result, the widths of the `html` element in your *home page* and *about page* are different. For instance, on my computer screen, the `html` element in the *home page* has a width of `1149px`. Meanwhile, the `html` element in the *about page* has a width of `1132px`. As you can see, the `html` width in the *about page* is smaller. Note that the width of the scrollbar may differ, but in my case, it has a width of `17px`.

So my `html` element has a smaller width in the *about page*. **So what?** Well, this causes the auto values of margin in the *home page* and *about page* to be different (because the *about page* needs less margin to center the `body` element). As a result, it **seems** like the `body` element is moving.

---

### Solution #1

What can we do? The most obvious solution is to hide the scrollbar visually. You can do this by giving [`scrollbar-width: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) to the `html` element. This still allows the user to scroll (using mouse wheel), but you simply can't drag the scrollbar anymore (because it isn't there visually). Run these two snippets in your browser, the `body` element shouldn't be moving.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>
    Nablo
  </title>
 
  <style>
html {
  background-color: white;
}
 
body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
 
a {
  color: #3273dc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
a:hover {
  color: #63ccff;
}
 
a:visited {
  color: #8559da;
}
h2 a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
nav a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
 
footer {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
  </style>
</head>
 
<body>
  <header>
    <h2>
      Nablo
    </h2>
    <nav>
<a href=./home.html>Home</a>
<a href=./docs.html>Docs</a>
<a href=https://google.com>Google</a>
<a href=./about.html>About</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
<content>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p><strong>Nablo</strong> is a light static site generator. It's :</p>
<ul>
<li><strong>Light</strong>.</li>
<li><strong>Fast</strong>.</li>
</ul>
</content>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Made wih ♥ using nablo
  </footer>
</body>
 
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>
    Nablo
  </title>

  <style>
html {
  background-color: white;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

a {
  color: #3273dc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #63ccff;
}

a:visited {
  color: #8559da;
}
h2 a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

footer {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h2>
      Nablo
    </h2>
    <nav>
<a href=./home.html>Home</a>
<a href=./docs.html>Docs</a>
<a href=https://google.com>Google</a>
<a href=./about.html>About</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
<content>
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
</content>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Made wih ♥ using nablo
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### Solution #2

The previous solution might be a little bad for user experience simply because the presence of a scrollbar means that the page can be scrolled. The absence of one means the contrary. Besides, scrolling by dragging the scrollbar directly is also a really common behavior. As an alternative, you can opt to use this other solution.

This solution is to give the `html` element a width of `100vw` (100% of the viewport width). What this means is that even when there is a scrollbar in your `html` element, the `html` element **will** stay at a width of `100vw` **before scrollbar** and the scrollbar will be added to the `html`. However, doing so makes the `html` element to have a width of more than `100vw`. Its width is now `100vw` + `scrollbar's width`. This will cause an overflow on the x-axis of the `html` element, thus causing a horizontal scrollbar to appear. We can remove the horizontal scrollbar using `overflow-x: hidden`.

Now, the scrollbar remains and your `body` element does not *move*. Try running these two snippets on your computer, you'll see that it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>
    Nablo
  </title>
 
  <style>
html {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
 
body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
 
a {
  color: #3273dc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
a:hover {
  color: #63ccff;
}
 
a:visited {
  color: #8559da;
}
h2 a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
nav a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
 
footer {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
  </style>
</head>
 
<body>
  <header>
    <h2>
      Nablo
    </h2>
    <nav>
<a href=./home.html>Home</a>
<a href=./docs.html>Docs</a>
<a href=https://google.com>Google</a>
<a href=./about.html>About</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
<content>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p><strong>Nablo</strong> is a light static site generator. It's :</p>
<ul>
<li><strong>Light</strong>.</li>
<li><strong>Fast</strong>.</li>
</ul>
</content>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Made wih ♥ using nablo
  </footer>
</body>
 
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>
    Nablo
  </title>

  <style>
html {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

a {
  color: #3273dc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #63ccff;
}

a:visited {
  color: #8559da;
}
h2 a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

footer {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h2>
      Nablo
    </h2>
    <nav>
<a href=./home.html>Home</a>
<a href=./docs.html>Docs</a>
<a href=https://google.com>Google</a>
<a href=./about.html>About</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
<content>
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.32</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Part 1.10.33</h2>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
</content>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Made wih ♥ using nablo
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is from the setting `margin: auto;` which centers the `body` automatically (but for one of the pages, the longer content, the width is a bit smaller.. thus the difference.)

However, one of the pages (home) has a `height` of over 1000px, and the other (about) page, is very low `height`

if you add to the css `html` tag the following:

```
html{
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to force the vertical scroll to be always visible, you will have the pages identical and not moving.

You can achieve the same by adding a `min-height` value of something relevant to your longest page `content`, which is mostly an unknown value, and for each visitor it might differ based on their screen size.